# Only include modules from Angular Material that I need

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower, angular-material

I'm using the module $mdDialog from Angular Material but I don't need the full library. Is it possible to only include the modules that I need in the project, and how can I do that? I have installed Angular Material with Bower and using Gulp in my project.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: So there is no way to solve this? My project is very slow when I'm using the full installation of Angular Material when I only need the dialog module.

Answer (score 3):

Soon Angular Material will turn into `v1.1.0` as a major release.

As an addition the `material-tools` repository will be *announced*.

Material Tools allows developers to build a custom Angular Material build with the most necessary components.

It also can build precompiled theme stylesheets, which improves the performance significantly.

Material Tools is already available, but still in beta.

> https://github.com/angular/material-tools

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment above, `$mdDialog` depends on angular-material.js, which depends on angular.js, angular-aria.js and angular-animate.js. I don't think there's any way around that.

Although you are using Angular Material I would like to suggest an alternative - [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/), which is similar to and consistent in style with Angular Material. This suggestion is related to you not wanting to load lots of dependencies.

The advantage of using Polymer is that you can include separate elements, for example [paper-dialog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog) - [demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-dialog)

From the [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-elements)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DevVersion answer could be more upto date then this one

My Solution:

You choose only the components you want, by making a custom angularjs build from  [angular material git repository](https://github.com/angular/material) as follows

- download or clone the [angular material](https://github.com/angular/material) repo.
- go the repository folder and execute "npm install" or "npm update"

**For custom js build**

In the "\gulp" folder edit the util.js, update the buildJs() function

```
    function buildJs () {
     // original code commented
     //var jsFiles = config.jsBaseFiles.concat([path.join(config.paths, '*.js')]);  
        
      var jsFiles = config.jsBaseFiles;
      
      //adding the paths of components you want
      jsFiles.push('src/components/icon/**/*.js');
      jsFiles.push('src/components/showHide/**/*.js');
      jsFiles.push('src/components/virtualRepeat/**/*.js');
      jsFiles.push('src/components/dialog/**/*.js');
```

- run "gulp build" and find the js files in "\dist" folder

I am using angularjs with webpack, I copied the "angular-material.js" to "\node_modules\angular-material" in my application and I was able to make a build without any changes.

**For building custom css**

edit "build-scss.js" in "\gulp\tasks" folder in the repository. edit the getPaths() function

```
function getPaths () {
    var paths = config.scssBaseFiles.slice();
    if ( modules ) {
      paths.push.apply(paths, modules.split(',').map(function (module) {
        return 'src/components/' + module + '/*.scss';
      }));
    } else {
     // original code commented
     // paths.push('src/components/**/*.scss');
      paths.push('src/core/services/layout/**/*.scss');
       
       //add the paths of components you want     
        paths.push('src/components/icon/**/*.scss');
        paths.push('src/components/showHide/**/*.scss');
        paths.push('src/components/virtualRepeat/**/*.scss');
        paths.push('src/components/datepicker/**/*.scss');
        paths.push('src/components/autocomplete/**/*.scss');
        paths.push('src/components/backdrop/**/*.scss');
        paths.push('src/components/dialog/**/*.scss');
```

- "gulp build" will also build css in the "\dist" folder

I hope it helps, please comment in case angular material gulp build is changed.

**Other way**

when you install angularjs with npm, you can find js and css files for each component in "\node_modules\angular-material\modules\js" you can use your custom build to concatinate them.