# Is there any Angular 4 library available for handling both notification popup and toaster?

Tags: angular, notifications

Currently is there any library available in Angular 4 for handling both notification popup and toaster.

Following links says about several components and libraries, but cant find a library for handling both notification popup and toaster.

1. [50 Plugins for Alerts and Notifications](https://libraries.io/explore/typescript-angular2-libraries?keywords=notification)
2. [notification angular2 libraries written in TypeScript](https://libraries.io/explore/typescript-angular2-libraries?keywords=notification)

several other components are found but nothing satisfies my requirement.

One more doubt,

Does the following question has any solution:
[Only include modules from Angular Material that I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784394/only-include-modules-from-angular-material-that-i-need)

Please help me... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Growl and messages from PrimeNg.

It's easy to use.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/growl

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/messages

Comment: Does this handle popup or alert type of notifications?

Comment: It does(not like modal). You can check examples on the link.

Comment: If you need some more advanced functionality you can also checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng-advanced-growl. This is just a wrapper around primeng-growl that offers you additional features like, unique lifetime for each message, pause on hover or limitation and caching of messages.